# Mroonga SQL Alter Table fails, '[object][register] failed to register a name: <#sql-8c0_13>: <grn_io_lock failed>:'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, alter-table, mysql2

I'm having a hard time finding any information on this error.

My situation is I'm running a migration to update column comments. Meaning I'm calling the alter table sql and writing the code you see in the error.
As far as I'm aware there's nowhere this should fail.

The jest of the error is :

```
Mysql2::Error: [object][register] failed to register a name:
<#sql-8c0_13>: <grn_io_lock failed>: ALTER TABLE `tablename`
    MODIFY `tablename_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_1_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_2_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_ja` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_ja_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_en` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_en_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `is_some_trait` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment ''
```

(column name references changed for simplicity/security)

Some possibly related information:

- This project has Japanese language involved
- I am currently using test data which I am unsure of the integrity of
- The amount of data in the table is moderately large for my computer specs and takes some time to process
- I was able to update most other tables in this same manner without any particular issues, except a few likely related tables.
- This table contains foreign key references.
- The migration seems to have succeeded once on the first or second attempt of running it, but fails every time now including on rollbacks which do essentially the same function. (no changes to the code on any attempt)
- This seems to happen when modifying any column, even with running directly in mysql.
- **All the tables related seem to use the Mroonga engine**

Does anyone know a solution to it that will allow me to update my column comments via migration? Any information is appreciated.

Here is the migration file

```
class UpdateCommentsForTablename < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    connection.execute("ALTER TABLE `tablename`
    MODIFY `tablename_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_1_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_2_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `name_ja` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `name_ja_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `name_en` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `name_en_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `is_some_trait` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント',
    MODIFY `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment 'コメント'")
  end

  def self.down
    connection.execute("ALTER TABLE `tablename`
    MODIFY `tablename_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_1_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `other_tablename_2_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_ja` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_ja_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_en` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `name_en_sub` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `is_some_trait` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment '',
    MODIFY `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL comment ''")
  end
end
```

Comment: Managed to get some more error info from running directly in mysql
`ERROR 1005 (HY000): [object][register] failed to register a name: <#sql-8c0_4>: <grn_io_lock failed>`

Comment: Maybe seems to be relevant? 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Perhaps posting your migration file would be helpful for people to spot a problem?